# How to add an image in Select2 options?

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I have a select:

```
<select data-bind="options : PeriodeOptions, optionsValue : 'Periode', 
optionsText : function(item) { return AddLock(item)}" id="SelectPeriode"></select>
```

And I have my fucntion;

```
//am - Fonction permettant d'ajouter le cadenas à côté de la Periode si elle est cloturée
        function AddLock(pItem) {
            if (!pItem.IsCloturePeriode)
                return pItem.Periode;
            var lTemplate = $('<span>' + pItem.Periode + '<img src="/Ressources/Images/Locked.png"/></span>');
            return lTemplate;
        };
```

It sends me an object: [image]
 Please help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure if the question is tagged incorrectly, but i don't see your select2 function in the code youve given

however here is a sample of select2 templating code that would use images in the select and the result

```
function formatData (data) {
  if (!data.id) { return data.text; }
  var $result= $(
    '<span><img src="/Ressources/Images/Locked.png"/> ' + data.text + '</span>'
  );
  return $result;
};

$("#SelectPeriode").select2({
  templateResult: formatData,
  templateSelection: formatData

});
```

Comment: Yes I do have a select2 function, it's just not shown in code.
I found actually the solution, it's simular to yours, but I like yours more.
I did: `<select data-bind="options : PeriodeOptions, optionsValue : 'Periode'" id="SelectPeriode"></select>` - I left options and optionValue (removed optionText).
And in templateResult and templateSelection I did:
`function (item) {
                var lTemplate = $(
                  '<span>' + item.text + '<img class="img-flag" src="/Ressources/Images/Locked.png"/></span>'
                );
                return lTemplate;
            },`