# How to insert <img> tag inside <option> tag?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jsp

I want to display an image file from the data I passed from Controller to JSP.

For example, when you send the following value from JSP,

```
{selectDoctor=[{d_name=MyName, d_imageServerPath=/boardFile/014e40e0ea.PNG, d_imagePath=C:/rachel/014e40e0ea.PNG, di_idx=2, d_imageOriginalName=testImage.PNG, d_idx=2, d_medicalInformation=valuevalue}]}
```

I have been able to display the value outside the  tag through the  statement.

```
<c:forEach items="${selectDoctor}" var="sD">
    <select>
        <option value="">Choice Doctor</option>
        <option value="${sD.d_idx}"><img src="${sD.di_imageServerPath}></img>${sD.d_name}</option>
    </select>
</c:forEach>
```

But unlike my expectations, the img tag does not work.

How do I insert the  tag inside the  tag?

Comment: you can use jQuery select2 plugin

Comment: select2 plugin? what's mean?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32847952/how-to-add-an-image-in-select2-options check this out

Comment: You can use jQueryUI - SelectMenu.
You can refer to this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2966006/8944409

Comment: You let me know what I do not know. Thank you very much. @Prateik

Comment: It is amazing how various methods exist !! @TanviSurve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source Link http://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#custom_render

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Selectmenu - Custom Rendering</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $.widget( "custom.iconselectmenu", $.ui.selectmenu, {
      _renderItem: function( ul, item ) {
        var li = $( "<li>" ),
          wrapper = $( "<div>", { text: item.label } );
 
        if ( item.disabled ) {
          li.addClass( "ui-state-disabled" );
        }
 
        $( "<span>", {
          style: item.element.attr( "data-style" ),
          "class": "ui-icon " + item.element.attr( "data-class" )
        })
          .appendTo( wrapper );
 
        return li.append( wrapper ).appendTo( ul );
      }
    });
 
    $( "#filesA" )
      .iconselectmenu()
      .iconselectmenu( "menuWidget" )
        .addClass( "ui-menu-icons" );
 
    $( "#filesB" )
      .iconselectmenu()
      .iconselectmenu( "menuWidget" )
        .addClass( "ui-menu-icons customicons" );
 
    $( "#people" )
      .iconselectmenu()
      .iconselectmenu( "menuWidget")
        .addClass( "ui-menu-icons avatar" );
  } );
  </script>
  <style>
    h2 {
      margin: 30px 0 0 0;
    }
    fieldset {
      border: 0;
    }
    label {
      display: block;
    }
 
    /* select with custom icons */
    .ui-selectmenu-menu .ui-menu.customicons .ui-menu-item-wrapper {
      padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 3em;
    }
    .ui-selectmenu-menu .ui-menu.customicons .ui-menu-item .ui-icon {
      height: 24px;
      width: 24px;
      top: 0.1em;
    }
    .ui-icon.video {
      background: url("images/24-video-square.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
    }
    .ui-icon.podcast {
      background: url("images/24-podcast-square.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
    }
    .ui-icon.rss {
      background: url("images/24-rss-square.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
    }
 
    /* select with CSS avatar icons */
    option.avatar {
      background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
      padding-left: 20px;
    }
    .avatar .ui-icon {
      background-position: left top;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="demo">
 
<form action="#">
  <h2>Selectmenu with custom avatar 16x16 images</h2>
  <fieldset>
    <label for="people">Select a Person:</label>
    <select name="people" id="people">
      <option value="1" data-class="avatar" data-style="background-image: url(&apos;http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b3e04a46e85ad3e165d66f5d927eb609?d=monsterid&amp;r=g&amp;s=16&apos;);">John Resig</option>
      <option value="2" data-class="avatar" data-style="background-image: url(&apos;http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e42b1e5c7cfd2be0933e696e292a4d5f?d=monsterid&amp;r=g&amp;s=16&apos;);">Tauren Mills</option>
      <option value="3" data-class="avatar" data-style="background-image: url(&apos;http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/bdeaec11dd663f26fa58ced0eb7facc8?d=monsterid&amp;r=g&amp;s=16&apos;);">Jane Doe</option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>
</form> 
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What you wrote is what I wanted.

Comment: Happy Coding @Seongwon-Choi

Comment: Thank's a lot :-)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot insert `tag` within `<option>`.`Options` tags cannot contain any other tags. Try to build you own `dropdown` using `<dd>` `<dl>` `tags`.

Comment: Those tags are known as HTML5 tags. It's allright??

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve this is to use Select2 plugin of jQuery it provides even more facilities you can check the [link](https://select2.org/) for documentation

Comment: There are too many ways. I do not know what to choose, and I am sorry that I did not think of many of these methods.

Comment: simple you can choose the method with which you like to work :-)

Comment: I have really broadened your choices. Thank you.